# How can I detect convex/concave curves in an Image?

Tags: python, opencv, curve, hough-transform

I am working on an OCR problem in which I have to extract the concave/convex curves. I extracted straight lines and circles using Hough Transform but I am not finding any appropriate library or method for curve detection. I tried generalised hough transform but it is I think generally suited for object detection rather a curve line detection. Lane detection method is also not helping. The dataset consists of many characters. I am attaching some of them.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlEgV.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMSeg.png)

Anyone with any idea or source for the same.

Comment: you can compute convexHull and measure convexityDefects or the distance between curve and convex bull

Comment: See https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/cv1/t